# Re using the components in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I have a component called `list` and it has `fab-button` with `icon` and `tooltip-text` it looks like this:

[image]

I thought of making it as **generic component**, so that i can re-use this component again.So I am reusing the `list`component in another components called **SCHOOL** &  **COLLEGE** like this:

[image]

I am re-using `list` component fine,but i want to change the `fab-button's` icon and the the `tooltip text(i,e add-school)` according the component in which it is present.

Means

1) If the `list` component is present in `SCHOOL` component the `fab-button` `icon` and `tooltip-text` should be different.

2) If the `list` component is present in `COLLEGE` component the `fab-button` `icon` and `tooltip-text` should be different.

How can i change `icons` and `tooltip-text` dynamically according to the **component** ?? I didn't found any resources for **components reusability**.

Here is the stackblitz [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-szxiea?file=app/app-routing.module.ts).

Comment: Add your `html` and ts to check more information about it

Comment: Use an `@Input` to pass the value into the list component

Comment: Since the code is long because of many components, i have created `stackblitz `link. @RahulSwamynathan

Comment: This concept is new for for me, if possible please edit in `stackblitz` .@user184994

Comment: We can pass input to the your list component for icon and tooltip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your current requirement, you need to have 3 `@input` and 1 `@Output`

```
  @Input()
  public tooltip;  //<-- pass tooltip text

  @Input()
  public buttonType; //<-- pass button style class

  @Input()
  public contacts;  //<-- pass contact from the college or school

  @Input()
  public add = new EventEmitter(); //<-- Emit Add event so that it can capture in the respective component College or School.
```

Working demo is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-udhiaz

Comment: Thanks for the answer, still the the icon inside `fab-button` is not changing. i,e  `<i class="material-icons" >person_add</i>`

Comment: I don't want to change the button, I just want to change the `icon`  inside the button according to the component.

Comment: Changed it to `fab-button`

Comment: Sorry i am bit confused, if possible edit in `stackblitz`.

Comment: Can you add one more button in your example, how it should like for other ?

Comment: I have edited the question, see the 2nd image

Comment: I just want to change the icon inside the button according to the component.

Comment: Now i am using icon(icon name: person-add) change to another icon (fr ex: delete)  when it is using in another component.

Comment: Updated, check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-udhiaz

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Input` for this.

In your list component TS file, add the input property:

```
 @Input()
 public tooltip;
```

In the template, use this value instead of the hardcoded value

```
<button mat-fab color="primary" id="add-button" [matTooltip]="tooltip"><i class="material-icons" >person_add</i></button>
```

Then, you can pass the value in, like so:

```
<app-list tooltip="Add School"></app-list>
```

**[Here is a Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-rwmeu1?file=app%2Fschool%2Fschool.component.html)**

Comment: `toltiptip` is changing fine but the `icons` are not changing.

Comment: Yep, I just gave an example. You just need to do exactly the same thing but for the icons

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to the `list` component as `@Input()` property - if its a `tooltip` you can just add as string and bind it in your `html` - if it icon you can send the icon directly

```
@Input() tooltips;
```

while passing from parent `<app-list tooltips="Add School"></app-list>`

```
<button mat-fab color="primary" id="add-button" [matTooltip]="tooltips"><i class="material-icons" >person_add</i></button>
```

Now the case you want to pass the icon - you can add using content projection

list.component.html

```
<div>
    <mat-selection-list  #contact>
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
            <a mat-list-item><span>{{ contact }}</span> </a>
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
```

Passing your icon when loading the component

```
<app-list>
   <button mat-fab color="primary" id="add-button" matTooltip="Add School"><i 
     class="material-icons" >person_add</i></button>
</app-list>
```

In this way you can change the icons even the tool tips based on the component loaded - if you are changing the icons based on the `class` names you can just pass the class name as another `@Input()` property to the child

Hope this helps you - Happy coding :)